# How to Provision Workflows with SharePoint Framework

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I'm shifting my development to SharePoint framework now and have met with this problem. How do I deploy/provision a workflow to SharePoint Online using SharePoint Framework Client Web part.

I couldn't find the sample or something like that in **MSDN**. I found something similar in PnP though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Workflow is not supported in SharePoint Framework**.

Use **PnP** or **Microsoft Flow** instead.