# SPFx - How to start workflow on list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

Do I want to start workflow where send an email with a new framework of SharePoint? [Is it true that I can not start a workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219953/how-to-provision-workflows-with-sharepoint-framework)?

**What should I use?**

- SPServices library
- [JSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148226/send-e-mail-from-javascript-using-rest-api)
- PnP?

Thank you previously!

Comment: This works glad for me --> [HERE](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-SP.Utilities.Utility)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom button to start a workflow on a List item. Here I have used SP services to achieve this. The whole logic lies in - how create a Url that redirects to Workflow initiation page? This url looks like this;

```
../sites/your_sitename/layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List="+your_List_guid+"&ID="+<your_ItemID>+"&TemplateID={"+WFguid+"}
```

Please refer to my [Complete Answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218198/how-to-trigger-workflow-from-button-in-o365/218204#218204)

Comment: This is very long, not suitable for modern programming.